# Java - cast to an interface, then find out what the casted type is

Tags: java, interface, casting

I am struggling a bit with class casting. Let me set the scene. I have java server code that uses a service and orchestrator layer. A request comes into the service layer in a bean format (java class aligned with the front end view), and then i have a bunch of domainBeanMapper classes which take a bean format object and translate it to a domain format object. Eg UserBean has a dateOfBirth represented by a string, while User has the dateOfBirth represented by a Date so the UserMapper.java will make the date string into a date object. So for each object in the system i have a *.java, *Bean.java and *Mapper.java (User.java, UserBean.java, userMapper.java).

in applicationContext i hold the relationship from each object to their mapper, like this:

```
<util:map id="domainBeanMappers">   
    <entry key="UserBean" value-ref="userMapper" />
    <entry key="User" value-ref="userMapper" />
.....
```

and then i define the mapper:

```
<bean id="userMapper" class="com.me.mapping.UserMapper" parent="baseDomainBeanMapper"/>
```

I call the domain bean mappers like this from my service layer:

```
UserBean userBean = (UserBean) getDomainBeanMapper().mapDomainToBean(user);
```

In the run of this code I find the mapper object that I want like this:

```
    DomainBeanMapper mapper = findApplicableMapper(myObject.getClass().getName());
    if (mapper == null) {
        mapper = findApplicableMapper(myObject.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
```

where findApplicableMapper works like this:

```
private DomainBeanMapper findApplicableMapper(String string) {
    return domainBeanMappers.get(string);
}
```

For the last few years, this has worked like a charm. For whatever object I want in the system i can easily pick out the relevant mapper and then translate from my bean format to domain format and vice-versa, based on the .getClass() call of any instance.

Now, I have a new requirement that is giving me trouble. I want to be able to translate from my User object to several sub-objects based on a parameter. So for some calls, i want just the id, firstName and lastName back. For other calls I want more fields, but still not the whole object, and then for some calls I want the whole object back like before. I don't want to go down the sub-objects path and end up with UserLight, UserLightWithName, UserLightWithNameButNoAddress, ... argh nightmare.

So instead I was hoping to create a bunch of interfaces representing "views". So the request comes in with the ViewType of Basic, and that means I want the user's personal details and address. So I wrote an interface called UserBasic, got User to implement it, and added a mapping from UserBasic to UserBasicMapper, and from UserBasicBean to UserBasicMapper, in the hope that I could make the translate call like this:

```
UserBasicBean restrictedUserReturn = (UserBasicBean) getDomainBeanMapper().mapDomainToBean((UserBasic)user);
```

but this doesn't work because getClass() always returns the instances class, not the interface that it has been cast to. I guess I can always add another paramater to the mapDomainToBean call which is the class that I want used, but the codebase is quite massive and I will need to touch on every call if i make that change.

So basically I'm looking for a way to cast an instance to an interface type and then find that interface type? Is this possible??

*crosses fingers*...

Comment: Why don't you want the whole object?

Comment: it's a security requirement. certain users of the system can only see certain parts of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of making interfaces that the user implements, why not make proxy classes that represent the limited versions? For example,

```
class UserBasic {

    private User user;

    public UserBasic(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return user.getFirstName();
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can add a `getUser() { return user; }` to get the full instance back.

This way you should be able to keep everything else the same and make a trade-off for the class over interface.

Comment: Ooh, this is nice!!! It will get me the same functionality and I will not have to change the domainBeanMapper code at all. UserBasic could also have a getUser() method to allow me to map in the other direction - for requests that supply the sub-object view. Yes, this is great!

Comment: ha, excellent, you added the getUser piece as I was writing my comment. Thank you so much for you time!

Comment: Glad to help!! @Margaret

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks. UserBasicBean restrictedUserReturn = (UserBasicBean) getDomainBeanMapper().mapDomainToBean(new UserBasic(user));

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can use **instanceof** keyword to check which type of object it is.

Comment: unfortunately that isn't really going to work as i would have to say

 if (myObject instanceOf UserBasic) {
  mapper = findApplicableMapper("UserBasic");
 } else if (myObject instanceOf AnotherView) {
  .....
 }

which would really dirty up my code. thanks for the thought though.

Comment: what I'm looking for is a way to take advantage of the code behind the implementation of instanceOf to find out what myObject is an instance of. it seems silly that this would not be available

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like writing few methods that differ with the paramenter type, example:

```
public class Test
{

    public static void n(Number n) {
        System.out.println("Number");
    }

    public static void n(Integer n) {
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        n(3); //will call the n(Integer n);
        n((Number)3); //will call the n(Number n);
    }
}
```

So yes, you can find out which type you have casted to by making multiple methods each taking proper parameter type and then processing it accordingly to type.

Comment: unfortunately I don't believe i can use this path. I am going to have my object implement multiple interfaces for the different views. All will be overlapping sets of the relevant getters and setters of the member variables. eg. User implements UserBasic, UserLight, UserLocation. then if I use the instanceof checks, it will return true for all of them as the User object implements them all. instead of checking what type I have just cast it to. Does that makes sense? I need to find out the specific interface that has just been cast.

Answer (score 0):

**Interface does not represent view - it defines a behaviour.** 
I guess you need some kind of factory (ckech these links for inspiration https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern , https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) here (or builder) 
If you say something about 'sub-objects' - try to extend UserBean class

```
class BaseUserBean extends UserBean {}
class AnotherUserBean extends UserBean {}
```

put the common stuff for all users into base class and something really specific to each of your sub-users let's say into children classes and then

```
 UserBean u = getDomainBeanMapper().mapDomainToBean(user);
```

...

```
//method mapToDomain should check your param and return the type you need
//ViewType can be a part of user or a separate param
UserBean mapDomainToBean(User user, ViewType vt) {
    if (vt == ViewType.BASE) {
      BaseUserBean obj = BaseUserBean ();
      // mapping here (set fields you need)
      return obj;
    }

    if (vt == ViewType.ANOTHER) {
      AnotherUserBean obj = AnotherUserBean ();
      // mapping here (set fields you need)
      return obj;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is certainly possible, thank you, but changing the mapDomainToBean signature will affect hundreds of spots and there is not currently time to regression test the whole system too carefully.